# How do I generate and package PDB files with NPanday?

Tags: .net, maven, maven-plugin

My coworkers and I are trying to use Maven to build our C# .NET webservice projects. After some research, NPanday seemed like the best choice. We have been successful in getting NPanday working with NUnit and a local Nexus artifact repository.

But now we're wondering if there is a way to create and package .pdb files for debugging (specifically because we have some projects that depend on other internal projects). We are using the dotnet-library packaging type with NPanday and it doesn't appear to have a way of doing this.

According to [the documentation](http://incubator.apache.org/npanday/docs/1.4.0-incubating/guide/advanced/project-types.html), it would seem that the custom-lifecycle-maven-plugin is what we need to use in order to create dotnet-symbols or dotnet-archive packages. But I'm not sure how to use it.

My guess is that using the custom-lifecycle-maven-plugin would require adding our own compilation and packaging (zipping) goals similar to what is described here: http://docs.codehaus.org/display/MAVENUSER/Using+Maven+to+manage+.NET+projects But doing that seems to remove much of the simplicity of using NPanday's maven-compile-plugin.

Can anyone help me sort this out? Thanks!

**Disclaimer:** My coworkers and I are very new to Maven and we are struggling to understand how to best apply it to our projects. Also, for the sake of this question, please assume that the use of Maven is non-negotiable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, since no one responded, I'm answering my own question based on what we learned here at work. Our solution: stop using NPanday altogether. It cannot do debug builds easily.

Aside from this particular issue, we found many other problems (or at least less-than-desirable) traits about NPanday. It uses the C# compiler (csc) instead of MSBuild, so we couldn't easily use EDMX for our database. Also we had to list every file to include with compilation.

We've migrated to using the `maven-dotnet-plugin` from Sonar (groupId: `org.codehaus.sonar-plugins.dotnet`). We've also had some success with defining our own custom Maven executions.

It's too bad that NPanday was such a let-down. It had a great resume, but in the end we had to fire it because it wasn't able to do the work we needed. Maybe someday it will improve enough to be useable.

I think we might have been able to make debug builds with with NPanday's `custom-lifecycle-maven-plugin`, but at that point it's questionable what NPanday is even helpful for. By the time you create custom executions, you might as well just avoid the pain of NPanday.

Comment: Sorry to hear that. I'm really interested in making NPanday work. I joined as a committer (in October 2011), and one of my first contributions was the custom-lifecycle-maven-plugin, just because I also just had to get things done, where NPanday got in the way.

Comment: Well, here's hoping that you and the NPanday team can improve the product. Once our concerns have been addressed, then we'd be happy to revisit the use of NPanday. I'd suggest at least adding an MSBuild option (to handle EDMX and simultaneously remove the need to have children pom files at the project level).

Comment: Oh, and props to you Lars for contributing to the project. If I had the time (or if my employer was willing) I would have liked to contribute instead of just complain. But at this point we're just a consumer.

Comment: Thanks to contributions from Viktor Stefoglo we now have support for PDBs on 1.5.0-SNAPSHOT. PDBs will be deployed as separate artifacts, but follow the DLLs in most part of the system (tests, application packaging, copy-dependencies, ++) see https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NPANDAY-402